# internationalization of a web application

Tags: java, internationalization

working on internationalizating a web application, I am a bit blocked, because I don't know how to make my .properties dinamic. I mean, to get automatically static text from the application. Now I have, for instance, this one MessageBundle_de_DE.properties:

```
greetings=Hallo!  
inquiry=Wie geth's?   
farewell=Tchüs!
```

But this is static, I wrote theese three couples (key, value).
How could I make my keys according to my application?? I guess this is possible, regarding on [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/TOC.html).

Using [Spring framework](http://rizafar.blogspot.com/2007/07/internationalization-spring-upon-it.html) and JSP technology.

Thanks in advance, I know this is maybe too general question.

Comment: What do you mean by *How could I make my keys according to my application?* ?

Comment: I suppose you want to know how to bind resource strings inside the web pages. Which framework are you using to develop the application? The binding technique changes according with technology.

Comment: There are some minor corrections needed in your example:  
inquiry=Wie geht's?   
farewell=Tschüs!

Comment: As others already said, it all depends on what technology you are using. It looks a bit different for JSP and GWT for example. So please re-edit your question in regards to specific technology you are using.

Comment: @romaintaz what I want to do is to make my .properties files dinamically. Maybe I have any other keys instead of 'greetings' or 'inquiry' which appear in my application. I want to get all this information automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using spring, add the following bean to your application context:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages/messages" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
</bean>
```

In your /WEB-INF/messages folder, create all the messages.properties files that you need i.e. messages_en_GB.properties, messages_DE.properties etc.

Then in your jsps, use the following spring provided tag:

```
<spring:message code="some.property.name" />
```

By default the locale should be the locale your user has set in their browser. To allow them to select a different Locale (and thus the correct language), you can also add this to your application context:

```
<!-- Saves a locale change using a cookie -->
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" />
<mvc:interceptors>
<!-- Changes the locale when a 'locale' request parameter is sent; e.g. /?locale=de -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Then, you just need links that include a locale property like `/?local=de` to change to a German translation.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Just 2 more questions: Where to put Messages.bundle and also, in code="some.property.name", do you mean code="Messages_de_DE.properties.key"?? And how to specify in which languaje I want the translation??

Comment: I've added a little more on how to pick your translation. Your messages.properties go in the folder I mention in my post. When I say code="some.property.name", the value there should be the key for whatever value you want output. In your given example this would be, for example, code="greetings".

Comment: Thanks again, but in the file I am testing this, I get Error Traced[line: 51] The prefix "spring" for element "spring:message" is not bound.

Comment: You'll need to include the Spring taglib on your page:

<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using a web application framework, I would suggest using the [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org), which provides useful functionality for web applications, including internationalization.

Comment: Thanks, I was already using Spring framework, and I understand how easy could be internationalize my application, but I am block, because I don't know how to continue and link the web with the configuration

Answer (score 0):

The best way to internalize your application if you don't use any framework is to use database to store all your translations. Just a simple class which would load translations from db by the key and your problem is solved.

Comment: It is not the best way to internationalize your application. It is far from the best, actually. It might be easy from developer stand point, but it will be a nightmare for Localization Engineers. It is a lot easier to correct (i.e. shorten) the translations when they are stored in properties files. Plus, how you suppose to modify CSS classes via DB?

Comment: @Pawel Why do you need to store css in db? And second, all you need for localization engineers is a simple script which puts all the localization data to the db.

Comment: I do not, but it is often needed to tweak CSS classes. As for the second part, funny thing but I had a meeting today with other Globalization Professionals and we talked about it. This idea is just brilliant, but there are two issues: 1. You will need another build to verify the fix. 2. All it takes is just one simple mistake (i.e. by translators) and the script won't install these translations.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for an easy and powerful way to internationalize your apps? Try gettext: http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html it's used by most open-source software for Linux, but it can also work with Java. The steps are easy:

- Write your program normally, as if it were non-localized: System.out.println("Hello world!!!")
- Somewhere in the code create public static class named (say) S with method _. This method name should be short as will be used often. It should delegate to Gettext or ResourceBundle APIs to get the message.
- All strings to localize surround with _(...): System.out.println(_("Hello world!!!"))
- Run gettext command to extract all such _ strings
- Translate extracted file to target languages
- Run gettext again to compile and check such files

This you can add localization to any application (whether it will be written in Java, C, Python or whatever) very easily.

Answer (score 0):

To internationalize applications I implemented a [Message Compiler](http://www.tmasoft.de/MessageCompiler/index.html), which creates the resource bundle files and constant definitions as Java enums or static final strings for the keys from one single source file. So the constants can be used in the Java source code, which is a much safer way than to use plain strings. The message compiler cannot only be used for Java. It creates also resource files and constants for Objective-C or Swift and can be extended for other programming environments.